# How to store day to day records from a mysql table to another?

Tags: php, mysql

Friends I have created a mysql table to get the page visits for my website.
My table is like this

```
statistics_table(stat_id,visited_page,visit_count)
```

Where the visit_count is incrementing by one for every visit.This works perfect. But now i need to to save all statistics in a different table each an every day to my traffic monitoring purpose.

like follows

```
2012/12/15-->page1-->100 visits
2012/12/16-->page1-->180 visits
2012/12/17-->page1-->200 visits
```

because statistics_table incrementing its value every day,so i can get how many visits per day using

```
(2012/12/16-->page1-->visits)-(2012/12/15-->page1-->visits)//80 visits
```

At the moment i am using an another table with same `schema+date` and update it everyday using cron job.

Is there any way to make this work rather than my way? I mean easy/better way to do this.Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query statement to insert datas to another table,

```
INSERT INTO Table_name(stat_id,visited_page,visit_count)
SELECT stat_id,visited,visit_count_page FROM Exist_Tablename WHERE <condition>;

DELETE FROM Exist_Tablename 
WHERE <condition>;
```

Like this you can try,

This may helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes this is what i doing now. What i am looking for is, if there any alternative rather than this any special function or any shortcut to copy day to day records.

Comment: By using this you can get the output... right..? May be this is the best way to do this.. lets try and see the output :)

Comment: @vinu => r u checking with this..? Did u get the output..?

Comment: No i didn't checked your answer as it is.But that is somewhat i have already done myself .That is why i told you i am using same way

Comment: At last i decided to use this method thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer above, but I recommend that you use MySQL events. See [CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) in the MySQL manual for more details.

In summary, your event should be:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE Every Day
    DO
      INSERT INTO Table_name(stat_id,visited_page,visit_count)
      SELECT stat_id,visited,visit_count_page FROM Exist_Tablename WHERE date_field =          
      DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

DELETE FROM Exist_Tablename 
WHERE date_field = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer that makes sense i will try it and let you know thanks friend

Comment: quick question.I have tried this but mysql cannot identify `Every Day` keyword am i missed something?

Comment: Just a note, `Every Day` should be `Every 1 Day`

Comment: Indeed Sorry by the typo